# Website appearing left aligned on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, css, html, mobile

I've been experimenting with html5 and have nearly finished a site for a friend. I have used Paul Irish's html5 boilerplate as a template and it all works fine until I view it in the iphone. It is at this point the site left aligns itself tight to the edge. I have set the container wrapping the site to margin:0 auto as usual, but for some reason I cannot get it to stay central.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Here is the current like to the site..

http://cynonvalleypals.co.uk.s88828.gridserver.com/

Thank you

Comment: FWIW, it looks fine in the Android simulator - center aligned.

Comment: I'm getting the issue on the iphone.. not tested it on android.. but thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You have set viewport via the `meta` tag, right?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It means iPhone will try to show your content in a 320px width viewport instead of a 980px one. Try to imagine what you will see if you open your website with a 320px width Chrome window? That's what you get in Mobile Safari.

You can debug this easily. Open a Chrome window and use developer tools to set the body's width to 320px. You will see the result. You can tune based on this setting or you can try to use other viewport setting.

Comment: I took that declaration out and still no joy.. Can you take a look at it your end? I'm still seeing it left aligned here...

Comment: The problem is the `#Kite` and the `footer`. If you put your page in a 980px wide Chrome, what do you see? `#container` is in the center of `body`, while `body` is not the whole page. When your Chrome window is 980px wide, the `body` is 980px wide and `#container` is in the center. But the `footer` is 1300px wide so it expands the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

try to use viewport in this way, I hope it will help you.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1040; user-scalable=no;" />
```

this will fix the width to 1040 but user will not allow to zoomed. you can add user-scaleable=1 in order to to allow users to zoom content.

Answer (score 0):

you try to set the width and margin-right:auto and margin-left:auto (do not use margin:auto)

[Check it](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/)

Comment: Tried this.. still left aligned :(